# using row number in update query - MySQL

Tags: mysql, db2, sql-update, row-number

I have this **DB2 query** which I want to make MySQL compliant :

```
UPDATE
(
 SELECT x.name, row_number() over () as rown from XYZ x where x.id = '123' and 
 x.div='abc')A
SET 
 A.name = 'name_1'
where 
A.rown<= ( select count(*) -1 from XYZ where id='123' and div='abc');
```

Now, I tried writing this I **MySQL**:

```
UPDATE 
(
  select x.name, (@row_number := @row_number +1) as rown 
  from XYZ x, (Select @row_number := 0)as t
  where x.id='123' and x.div='abc'
) A
Set
 A.name = 'name_1'
where
 A.rown<= ( select count(*) -1 from XYZ where id='123' and div='abc');
```

However, it gives me the error: `The target table A of the UPDATE is not updatable`

I have tried multiple ways but all in vain. Where am I going wrong? 
Also if the DB2 query can be made into MySql in any other way, since Mysql doesn't support 
`row_number()`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're selecting row numbers, but you haven't specified any ordering of the table, so it will just pick random rows. What is this query supposed to do?

Comment: You can't update a derived table, only a real table. You need to have the query that generates row numbers return return the IDs. You can then join that with the real table and update those rows. But it still doesn't make any sense without an `ORDER BY` in the subquery that generates row numbers.

Comment: What Barmar said, plus using session variables in a MySQL update may not work as intended.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm pretty sure they work fine.

Comment: @Barmar In DB2 the row_number works fine without any order. Well the query is supposed to update all the entries with `id='123' and div='abc'`, except for the very last entry as you can see it is specified in the where clause : `A.rown<= ( select count(*) -1 from XYZ where id='123' and div='abc');`

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a derived table. You need to join with the real table so you can update it.

```
UPDATE XYZ AS x
JOIN (
    select x.id, (@row_number := @row_number +1) as rown 
    from XYZ x, (Select @row_number := 0) as t
    where x.id='123' and x.div='abc'
) AS A ON x.id = A.id
Set X.name = 'name_1'
where A.rown <= ( select count(*) from XYZ where id='123' and div='abc');
```

I'm not sure if this will do the same thing as the DB2 query, though. It seems to assume some inherent ordering in the table, and perhaps DB2 provides such a thing, but MySQL doesn't make any guarantees about ordering when you don't use `ORDER BY`. If you add `ORDER BY x.id` in the subquery, maybe that will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar.  I shall give it a try and update you.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 you can do it :

```
update XYZ f1
set f1.name='name_1'
where f1.id='123' and f1.div='abc' 
and rrn(f1) not in 
( 
   select max(rrn(f2)) from XYZ f2 where f2.id='123' and f2.div='abc'
)
```